# About emmc file block mapping

Tags: linux, android, ext4

I successfully locate a file on ext4 filesystem. For example, the beginning 4k block of the file "cyclic.txt" is 105441. But when it read it from emmc card directly ,the first emmc block is not there but changed to 5168904. I just search through the entire emmc memory to get it but it's very slow. How to get the real location directly? Can I just use it for latter secure erase operation? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Do the locations use the same units? I.e. byte-based, 512b-block-based, 4k-block-based, etc.?

Comment: no the 105441 use the 4k-block-based while the 5168904 use the 512-block-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block numbers used by ext4 --- which you can find by using debugfs's "stat" command or by using "filefrag -v" are logical 4k block numbers.  That is, they are in units of 4k, relative to the beginning of the partition.

If you use a program like fdisk or gdisk, it will give you the partition start in 512 byte sectors.

So here's an example.  Suppose you want to find the location of /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-2-amd64.  (Which, using the command "df /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-2-amd64", we find is located on /dev/nvme0n1p4 as the /boot file system.)   You can find out the logical block numbers that are in use multiple ways:

- filefrag -v  /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-2-amd64
- debugfs -R "extents vmlinuz-4.19.0-2-amd64" /dev/nvme0n1p4
- debugfs -R "stat vmlinuz-4.19.0-2-amd64" /dev/nvme0n1p4

With any of these mechanisms, we will find that the file is using block numbers 60416-61680.

To find out where they are relative to the beginning of /dev/nvme0n1p4, multiple those block numbers by 4096 if you want byte offsets, or by 8 if you want them in units of 512 byte sectors.

If you want where they are relative to the beginning of the device (e.g., /dev/nvme0n1 in this case), you can look it up by the command:

- cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/nvme0n1p4/start

Or you can use the gdisk command and print out the partition table.  On both cases, this will give you the starting location of the partition "p4" in units of 512 byte sectors.

Final note:  Sometimes people will say LBA numbers when they are talking about 512 sector numbers as used by the Linux kernel, but you need to be a bit careful.  From the storage device's perspective, LBA stands for Logical Block Addresses, and are in units of whatever the storage device considers to be its logical block size.   For most devices historically, the logical block device sizes of nearly all storage devices was 512 bytes.  There were exceptions, such as IBM Mainframe DASD's, which had a 2048 byte sector size, but 512 was the effective standard.  With modern storage devices, there are some "advanced format HDD"'s, for example, which use 4k logical block size, and if you attach a SATA analyzer between the CPU and the HDD, you will see I/O requests being sent in units of 4k LBA numbers.  However, the Linux kernel assumes at the block device layer that all numbers are in units of 512 byte sectors, even though that may not be true that the device driver level.   Most of us won't have SCSI or SATA bus analyzers hanging around your workbench, so this distinction probably won't matter too much unless you are debugging or writing a device driver for a Host Bus Adapter.   So there's no real harm done by using the terminology "LBA" when referring to 512 byte sectors.   It's very commonly done, and if you only worry about things from the perspective of the Linux kernel and its userspace utilities, there's no harm done.  However, there are people who like to be nitpicky about such things, and if you are the sort of person who likes to believe they are moral superior by pointing out when people should be using KiB instead of KB, now you know another way you can be annoying nitpicky.  :-)

Comment: Thank you very much and I don't know how to appreciate you properly! ;-)